# Wordpress jQuery update URL for Post Pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I'm using the code below to update the paginated content for a Wordpress post within a specific div (postContent). It works perfectly except I would love the URL to update based on which page of content i'm on. Just like how it normally does if you use wp_link_pages without this code.

Thank you

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#content').on('click', '#pagination a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).load(link + ' #content', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use history.js to manipulate that.

```
(function(window,undefined){

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    });

    // Change our States
    History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.pushState({state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"); // logs {state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"
    History.replaceState({state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.pushState(null, null, "?state=4"); // logs {}, '', "?state=4"
    History.back(); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.back(); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.back(); // logs {}, "Home Page", "?"
    History.go(2); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"

})(window);
```

Check their github for more information.

[history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)